# How do I run a function on each argument in a varargs list in C

Tags: mysql, c, variadic-functions

I wish to Call mysql_real_escape on each argument of a vararg list before it is then passed on to vsprintf to include into an SQL string, is there anyway I can do this easilly?
Seems I missed prepared statements, this seems to be usefull though anyway.

Comment: Why are you constructing an SQL string with vsprintf?  You should almost certainly be using a prepared query.

Comment: using the C API, there is only two query functions, both of which accept a pure stirng only

Comment: on second thought, it seems I missed some of the manual, that may be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `va_start()` (and `va_end()`) twice.

The first time in a loop with `va_arg()` inside to test (and change) each argument;
and the next time for `vsprintf`

```
/* check args */
va_start(val, parm);
while (MORE_ARGUMENTS) {
    arg = va_arg(val, char*);
    /* mysql_real_escape(arg); */
}
va_end(val);

/* print */
va_start(val, parm);
vsprintf(buf, FORMAT_STRING, val);
va_end(val);
```

Comment: va_arg is not C89; #include <stdarg.h> is missing.

Comment: @user411313: I assumed the OP already had the includes he needed in place. He needed `<stdarg.h>` for `vsprintf()`. My copy of K&R has references to `<stdarg.h>`, va_arg, and friends (eg: pg. 155) so I assume it's in the C89 Standard, but can't be bothered to check just right now